# ArrayList in ArrayList in C#?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I want to have an ArrayList in an ArrayList. This is how I did it:

```
ArrayList arraylist1 = new ArrayList();

ArrayList arraylist2 = new ArrayList();
arraylist2.Items.Add("test1");
arraylist2.Items.Add("test2");

arraylist1.Items.Add(arraylist2);
```

Now how can I call the arraylist?

I tried it this way:

```
arraylist1[0][0].ToString()
arraylist1[0][1].ToString()
```

It didn't work. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: use a generic list `List<string>`  instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: What is the reason for using ArrayList rather than List<T>?

Comment: a) ArrayList is deprecated for List<T>. b) _It didn't work_ is not a helpful error description.

Comment: As the [ArrayList documentation itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8) says - "_**We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development.** Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List<T> class. The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance._"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way using Generic `List<string>` and `List<List<string>>` types found in [System.Collections.Generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1)-namespace:

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string>();
listOfStrings.Add("test1");
listOfStrings.Add("test2");

var listOfStringLists = new List<List<string>>();
listOfStringLists.Add(listOfStrings);

Console.WriteLine(listOfStringLists[0][0]);
Console.WriteLine(listOfStringLists[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array list you use just returns objects, so you'd have to cast the outer entry 1st:
`((ArrayList)arraylist1[0])[0]`

As it was already proposed above, better use the generic List